# Script to replace UpperCamel case keys with lowerCamel case keys in JSON file

Tags: json, bash, key, tcl, camelcasing

Would like ideas for the easiest way to do this to multiple files(example below). I prefer TCL. Can this be done easily with regsub?

Note: Only want keys to change to lowerCamel case, not the values.

```
"FooBar": [
        {
            "NumOne": "Hello",
            "SecondThing": true,
```

to

```
"fooBar": [
        {
            "numOne": "Hello",
            "secondThing": true,
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh

while {! [eof stdin]} {
    gets stdin line
    if [regexp {(^.*")([A-Z])([^"]+"\s*:.+)} $line x a b c] {
        set line [join [list $a [string tolower $b] $c] ""]
    }
    puts $line
}
```

and say:

```
./thisscript.tcl < file.json
```